# CSS background propriety don't add more then 2 images

Tags: html, css, image, background, scroll

I'm trying to create a website with images you scroll through and I'm using the CSS background element and I'm adding multiple images but for some odd reason when I'm adding the third image the second one is collapsing behind the first one and the third one takes his place. Here's an image:
http://i59.tinypic.com/a2syt1.jpg

```css
/* reset browser styles */
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* end of browser styles */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanshebrew.css);

#logo {
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

nav {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 padding: 5px 0;
}
nav li {
 display: inline;
 padding: 0 20px;
}
nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}

nav a:hover {
 color: rgb(207, 207, 207);
}

body {
 background: url("../images/wedding.png") no-repeat,
 url("../images/earrings.png") no-repeat, url("../images/watch.png");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="he-IL" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SD עיצובים</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <header div="mainHeader">
    <nav div="mainNav">
     <ul>
      <img id="logo" src="images/title.png"/>
      <li><a href="index.html">דף הבית</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">אודות</a></li>
      <li><a href="jewelery.html">תכשיטים</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">צור קשר</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </header>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unless you use actual images we can't see the actual problem

Comment: There's an actual image I've added the link before the code Paulie_D.

Comment: Images in the demo...not an image of the problem.

Comment: You should also be aware that an image as a child of a `ul` is invalid HTML.

Comment: Thanks for noting that but the image is the logo presented as part of the horizontal navigation and therefore the browser treats it as such. Why is it bad and how do you suggest me to write it?

Comment: Put it before the `ul` would be the appropriate way and then position it to taste.

Comment: Alright but why is it invalid if I'll do it as you suggested it will make my code longer which is less efficient isn't it?

Comment: Why...because that's the spec. Code longer...not really.

Comment: Ok. And about the images in the demo why are they necessary isn't it a syntax problem?

Comment: You seem to be asking for multiple images but telling them all to cover...if you want them to be positioned one on top of the other so that they scroll into view you would have to position them individually. That said, it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Exactly that :D I haven't made myself clear I'm trying to position them one on top of the other. Can the CSS stack them automatically or do I need to position them manually and if the latter how do I do that?

Comment: Frankly, I'd just use separate divs each with an single bg image...easier all round.

Comment: And they'd stock based on the div order?

Comment: That would be the default.

Comment: Thanks a lot! and also thanks for your consistency :D